# Windows XP SP3 - Freezes at "Preparing for Hibernate" (or StandBy) caused by Bluetooth driver

Tags: windows-xp, bluetooth, hibernate, suspend

Dell Lattitude E6410, 4GB ram, Windows XP SP3.

I've had it for about 6 months, it has been very well behaved, no unexpected problems to speak off.

Then suddenly, in the last three days, it froze twice on "Preparing to Standby" and then yesterday it froze on "Preparing for Hibernate".

The only solution was to fully power down and power up again.

On on occasion, I saw a dialog box about the bluetooth driver. So I disabled it. Thus far, things seem to have gone back to normal.

Is anyone familiar with bluetooth drive problems? Or any Windows level logging that relates to power management?

Comment: FYI: I never fixed this. For other reasons, my system was re-imaged with W7.